# How to cast object correctly

Tags: c#, json, object, asp.net-core-6.0

I have this code:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/21G0of

Basically I am curious, about how to cast the object2 - ResponseErrorForSlack to the same format as is the object1 - it should be the same - as can be seen when I serialize both objects to JSON, but when I use JsonResult - the content of the object is different.

Code overview:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> dict = new();
        dict.Add("endOfShiftBlock" ,"End time must be later than start time!");
        object object1 = new { response_action = "errors", errors = dict };
        
        ResponseErrorForSlack object2 = new("errors", "endOfShiftBlock", "End time must be later than start time!");
        
        string json1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object1);
        string json2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object2);
        
        Console.WriteLine("This is Json from Object1 :" + json1);
        Console.WriteLine("This is Json from Object2 :" + json2);
        Console.WriteLine();
        
        JsonResult jr1 = new JsonResult(object1);
        JsonResult jr2 = new JsonResult(object2);
        
        Console.WriteLine("This is correct:      " + jr1.Value);
        Console.WriteLine("This is not correct:  " + jr2.Value);
    }
    
}
class ResponseErrorForSlack
{
    public ResponseErrorForSlack(string responseAction,string blockId = null, string error = null)
    {
        ResponseAction = responseAction;
        if(blockId is not null && error is not null)
        {
            Errors = new()
            {
                { blockId, error }
            };
        }
    }

    public ResponseErrorForSlack(string responseAction, Dictionary<string, string> errors)
    {
        ResponseAction = responseAction;
        if (errors is not null)
        {
            Errors = errors;
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty("response_action")]
    public string ResponseAction { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("errors")]
    public Dictionary<string, string> Errors { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you see in your Console is the output of ToString().

Add the following override to your class `ResponseErrorForSlack`:

```
    public override string ToString() {
        return "Test";
    }
```

and you will see following output:

```
This is Json from Object1 :{"response_action":"errors","errors":{"endOfShiftBlock":"End time must be later than start time!"}}
This is Json from Object2 :{"response_action":"errors","errors":{"endOfShiftBlock":"End time must be later than start time!"}}

This is correct:      { response_action = errors, errors = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String] }
This is not correct:  Test
```

A check after your Console.WriteLines, shows up in output as well.

```
        if (jr2.Value.GetType() == typeof(ResponseErrorForSlack))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Yeah its correct");
        }
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is a solution to my problem... 

But I have solution I just put this to my class : 
`public object GetObject() { return new { response_action = ResponseAction, errors = Errors };}`
And I will call GetObject to have casted object - but still not sure if this is what is the correct way...

Comment: Assuming that you want JSON data for your consumer / client than the JsonResult uses a JsonSerializer internally. See: [SourceCode of JsonResult](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/main/src/System.Web.Mvc/JsonResult.cs)